# Why do elements in Python for ... in ...: statements use byValue behavior?

Tags: python, numpy, iteration

I can't seem to find an explanation anywhere for this...

Suppose I have a vector y initialized to all zeroes:

```
from numpy import *
y = zeros(5)
```

It could also be a plain python array, I don't think it really matters.

I noticed that the behavior of the `for x in y:` statement is that it makes a *copy* of each element in y, thus when you modify x, it does not modify y.

```
for x in y:
    x = 1
print y

output : array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])
```

My question is the following : Why is that so? I thought in Python everything was all byReference and that there is very little byValue passing around?

How could I do the following, using referenced variables? Doing the following seems to work :

```
for i in range(len(y)):
    y[i] = 2*rand()-1
```

But from what I know about Python, this is *wrong* and I believe it will be slow when I start using vectors of thousands or millions of values.

What else could I do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can replace this:

```
y = np.zeros(5)
for i in range(len(y)):
    y[i] = 2*rand()-1
```

with:

```
y=2*np.random.rand(5)-1
```

---

If y is a Python sequence (tuple, list, array, etc) or Numpy array,

`for x in y:`

iterates through `y`, setting `x` to each element in `y`.
If the elements are immutable objects like `str`, `int`, `float` or a Numpy numeric type,
then changing the value of `x` does not change the value in `y`.

If the elements are mutable objects, such as a `list`, then mutating the `list` will affect `y`.

Think of it this way: `x` is "pointing" to an object:

```
y---> [o----o----o----o]
            ^
            |
            x
```

When you write an assignment statement:

```
x += 1
```

Now you are reassigning `x` to "point" to a different object:

```
y---> [o----o----o----o]

x---> o
```

On the other hand, if you mutate a list with, say, `x.append(1)`, then
`x` still points to the same object (e.g. a list), but you've mutated the contents of that list.

Answer (score 4):

Python *does* use "references" only. But what is called "reference" in Python (and Java, and propably a handful of other languages) is not like in "pass-by-reference" or "references in C++". When you iterate over something like `for i in iterable:`, `i` points to the current item. But when you do `i = ...` in the loop, you're overwriting that reference with a new one instead of replacing the object pointed to. So actually, Python (and all the other languages mentioned) are pass-by-value. Except that those values are *always* (kind of) pointers.

Note that this does not apply for `i.attr = ...`! Setting members is different, it's a method call (one of `.__setitem__` of the object's `__dict__`, `.__setattr__` or `.__setattribute__` afaik). So if you did `i.some_member` in the loop, you would indeed alter the items of the iterable. Also note that this is of course moot with immutable objects like numbers or strings - you cannot possibly alter those.

If you want to alter e.g. a list directly, you need to use indices (although you shouldn't need `range(len(...))`, you can use `enumerate(the_list)` and you get indices *and* the current items). Also consider generating the values you want in the first place by using e.g. a list comprehension.

Comment: Awesome, I had been looking for something like enumerate for quite some time :D

Answer (score 1):

Please someone correct me if I am wrong, but the integer type in Python is not mutable and that is why when you perform some operation on one of the elements of the vector you get back a new object. I looked and looked but haven't found any confirmation of this hunch but when I try

```
>>> def zeros(length):
...     vector = []
...     for each in range(length):
...         vector.append([0])
...     return vector
... 
>>> zeros(8)
[[0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0]]
>>> y = zeros(8)
>>> for x in y:
...     x[0] += 1
... 
>>> y
[[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]]
```

and we know that lists are mutable we get what we expect.

Comment: Interesting. Can someone else confirm whether this is clean and safe to use?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how that code sample is wrong at all - as long as `y` is accessible from the scope that the `for` loop is in, all should be good.